# How to find button inside div using python & selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button 'users' inside a the following div:

```
 <div class="tabs">
   <button tab="0" >Users</button>
   <button tab="1">Groups</button>
   <button tab="2">Lifecycle Management</button> 
   <button tab="3">Features</button>
   <button tab="4">Databases</button>
 </div>
```

I already tried using this but it didnt work

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.tabs button.users"))
```

Anyone got a clue? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Users` it the text, not a class. You can't use `CssSelector` to locate by text, but you can use `Xpath`

```
driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class='tabs']/button[.='Users']"));
```